# How to get value first clicked 20฿ and change to 250฿ how to get current value i clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
prices.forEach(price => {
  price.addEventListener('click', e => {
    prices.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.classList.add('active');

    const currentValue = e.target.value;
  })
})
```

```html
<ul class="money">
  <li class="price" data-value="20">20 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="50">50 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="100">100 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="250">250 ฿</li>
  <ul>
```

My problem:

- When i change value, value is store multiple in currentValue
  variable.
- (I want to get 1 value)
- please explain to me and post website for more understand.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `data-value` can be found as `price.dataset.value` in your script:

```js
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
prices.forEach(price => {
    price.addEventListener('click', e => {
       prices.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
       e.target.classList.add('active');

       const currentValue = e.target.dataset.value;
       console.log(currentValue)
    })
})
```

```html
<ul class="money">
  <li class="price" data-value="20">20 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="50">50 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="100">100 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="250">250 ฿</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `e.target.value` is used to get input element's value.

To get an element's text value, you need to use `element.textContent`.
If you want to get the value from data attribute, you can use `element.dataset.value`.

```js
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
prices.forEach(price => {
    price.addEventListener('click', e => {
       prices.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
       e.target.classList.add('active');

       const textValue = e.target.textContent;              // get the list's text-value
       const currentValue = e.target.dataset.value + " ฿";  // get the list's data-value
       console.log(textValue, currentValue)
    })
})
```

```html
<ul class="money">
  <li class="price one" data-value="20">20 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="50">50 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="100">100 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="250">250 ฿</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method to get your value. Also, just as an aside, you can use [event delegation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/event-delegation-in-javascript/) to simplify your javascript plus you only need one event listener on the parent rather than one on each `li` as follows:

```js
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
document.querySelector('.money').addEventListener('click', e => {
  prices.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
  e.target.classList.add('active');
  const currentValue = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
  console.log(currentValue);
})
```

```css
.active {
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="money">
  <li class="price" data-value="20">20 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="50">50 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="100">100 ฿</li>
  <li class="price" data-value="250">250 ฿</li>
<ul>
```